# How to override user field for Token model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to override **Token** model:

```
class CustomerToken(Token):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but receive an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'user' in class 'CustomerToken' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Token'
```

As stated in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted):

> In Django, this is not permitted for attributes that are Field
>   instances (at least, not at the moment). If a base class has a field
>   called author, you cannot create another model field called author in
>   any class that inherits from that base class.

How to override **user** field for **Token** model in Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom authentication by extending the Token model then you have to remove "rest_framework.authtoken" from installed apps. and write down your own authentication in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES.